# Flutter: Divider not showing in Row Widget

Tags: flutter

The question says itself what is the problem

**Code Snippet:**
Below code working fine for `Column`, but when I replaced it with `Row`, it's not showing Divider on the screen.

```
 Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Divider(
            thickness: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 50,
          ),
          Divider(
            thickness: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Row Widget required to be used Divider with `Expanded/Flexible` Widget

```
    Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Divider(
              thickness: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Divider(
              thickness: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```